# Jira velocity release notes - linked issues, attachment and release date var

Tags: jira, velocity, vtl, release-notes

maybe you guys can help me.
I would like to edit the release notes and started to build my own vm file. So far so good.
Unfortunately I still can't find any reasonable documentation for the single possible VTL variables. Is there any at all?
I could only find information about a few variables here in the forum:
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Jira-Release-Notes-Template-Documentation/qaq-p/45533 where i asked this question, too.

Or maybe you can help me.
I still need the following information, which I want to display in my releasenotes.vm file:

- the release date
- the individual links on the respective issue
- And if possible, links to the attachments on the respective issue.

You would help me a lot with this.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Can noone help me?